# Disable Blue Highlight when Touch/Press object with Cursor:Pointer

Tags: html, css, mobile, touch, highlight

There is a blue highlight that appears whenever a Div that has the cursor:pointer property applied is touched in Chrome.
How can we get rid of it?

I have tried the following:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

But they do not affect the blue highlighting on press of a cursor.

Answer (score 203):

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

Takes care of the problem, as it sets the highlight color transparent.

Source: http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/alternative-to-webkit-tap-highlight-color-in-phonegap-apps/

Comment: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;` is also fine.

Answer (score 125):

As far as I have known,Vlad K's answer could cause problems in some android devices.Better solution:

```css
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Please clarify which answer alternate of "answer above"

Comment: why have you used `rgba(0,0,0,0)` instead of `rgba(255,255,255,0)`

Comment: @GauravAggarwal The **alpha** space makes sense
,so there is no difference between rgba(0,0,0,0) and rgba(255,255,255,0).This is just a case i think.Does rgba(255,255,255,0) acts weird?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal anything wrong? some early versions of webkit-based browsers doesn't support the **rgba** color declaration.transparent keyword based on **opacity** property, which been supported well.for browsers support rgba,**rgba(x,y,z,0)** are all transparent.

[rgba support info here](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Comment: If you're going to override it with transparent anyway, why have an rgba declaration at all? Are there WebKit versions that somehow don't support the transparent keyword on this property?

Comment: @BoltClock .I really can't find 'transparent' keyword in [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color) so i think it's not standard.Before I answer this question I have read [this article](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/essential-phonegap-css-webkit-tap-highlight-color.html),**Christian Cook **'s comment advice to add this because he cames into problem with some sumsung device.I think it's a bug of specific device.

Comment: why not just `#0000`

Comment: @punund have a check of caniuse info https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa

Comment: @ObooCheng it says it's not supported only by Chrome older than 62, which is 0.8% of all installed base.

Comment: yea, why should we drop the 0.8% since the rgba goes well? what's the benefit of #0000, shorter?

Answer (score 38):

Simply add this to your stylesheet and simply add the `class="no_highlights"` attribute to the element you wish to apply this class to.

```css
    .no_highlights{
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
```

or you can do this globally for all the elements by removing class name and doing this.

```css
    button,
    textarea,
    input,
    select,
    a{
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    
    }
```

Thanks :)
but anyway, the blue border is there as an accessibility feature. It looks bad but, It helps someone who needs it most.

Comment: Please note that you shouldn't use (-*-)user-select:none on the input/select/textarea elements. This gives loads of trouble in Safari on iOS; ending up with no keyboard popping op when trying to focus on these elements.

Comment: If you remove it, replace it with another visual indicator.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color) you can simply do this:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* for removing the highlight */
```

It works for me on Chrome 68 for Android and Chrome 80 on Windows.

Answer (score 11):

add to css

#### css

```css
html {
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

#### tailwind

```css
@layer base {
  html {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Comment: you should specify that this is for Tailwind CSS