# How to use Star rating for amp CSS with Django template Tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I want to only display the star rating on amp pages as per values available in the database using django template tags. How do I do that as my ratings are float type and also can that code be used for non-amp pages as well.

```
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>



<style amp-custom>
  .rating {
    --star-size: 3;  /* use CSS variables to calculate dependent dimensions later */
    padding: 0;  /* to prevent flicker when mousing over padding */
    border: none;  /* to prevent flicker when mousing over border */
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override; direction: rtl;  /* for CSS-only style change on hover */
    text-align: left;  /* revert the RTL direction */
    user-select: none;  /* disable mouse/touch selection */
    font-size: 3em;  /* fallback - IE doesn't support CSS variables */
    font-size: calc(var(--star-size) * 1em);  /* because `var(--star-size)em` would be too good to be true */
    cursor: pointer;
    /* disable touch feedback on cursor: pointer - http://stackoverflow.com/q/25704650/1269037 */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  /* the stars */
  .rating > label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.1em;  /* magic number to overlap the radio buttons on top of the stars */
    width: calc(var(--star-size) / 3 * 1.1em);
  }
  .rating > *:hover,
  .rating > *:hover ~ label,
  .rating:not(:hover) > input:checked ~ label {
    color: transparent;  /* reveal the contour/white star from the HTML markup */
    cursor: inherit;  /* avoid a cursor transition from arrow/pointer to text selection */
  }
  .rating > *:hover:before,
  .rating > *:hover ~ label:before,
  .rating:not(:hover) > input:checked ~ label:before {
    content: "★";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: gold;
  }
  .rating > input {
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(3);  /* make the radio buttons big; they don't inherit font-size */
    transform: scale(var(--star-size));
    /* the magic numbers below correlate with the font-size */
    top: -0.5em;  /* margin-top doesn't work */
    top: calc(var(--star-size) / 6 * -1em);
    margin-left: -2.5em;  /* overlap the radio buttons exactly under the stars */
    margin-left: calc(var(--star-size) / 6 * -5em);
    z-index: 2;  /* bring the button above the stars so it captures touches/clicks */
    opacity: 0;  /* comment to see where the radio buttons are */
    font-size: initial; /* reset to default */
  }
  form.amp-form-submit-error [submit-error] {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

The webpage consists of several products whose star rating needs to shows in their card div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the above code just to display the star rating as it is for accepting the star rating. As amp pages don't support js, you can do it with the help of css. What you need to do is place a blank star rating image and then overlap it with a filled up image of exact same size and use the clip with django template tags to show it as it is.

```
<img style="position: absolute;clip: rect(0px,{{i.rating}}px,0px,0px);top: 0px;left: 0px" src="https://filled-up-star.png"/>
```