# How to remove blue-box-fill when clicking the buttons?

Tags: css

Here's a gif that I've screen recorded on my device where you can see the blue-box-fill that I'm talking about:

[image]

I've tried doing this:

```
* {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
};

button, 
button:active, 
button:focus {
  outline: none;
};
```

But it doesn't do the trick of getting rid of that blue-box-fill, since it's not really a focus border or `outline`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

Comment: No, the problem's not the border or the outline @StephaneVanraes because I've already taken care of that. Have you watched the video attached carefully?

Comment: If your browser is firefox, it has an extra border that is neither the border not the outline, this is what is explained in the linked question. I will be honest, I do not really see the problem in your video, maybe you can post a screenshot as well ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Blue Highlight when Touch/Press object with Cursor:Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704650/disable-blue-highlight-when-touch-press-object-with-cursorpointer)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The property you're looking for is [tap-highlight-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color)

`-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;`

Comment: This is just why I hate CSS, was looking at outline, box-shadow, focus-within and anything but this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this is happening on iOS?

This should prevent the blue box from appearing:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @doctypecode. But no, it's happening on all operating systems, not just on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you want like this ..**

```css
button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #0095ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

#btn2 {
  outline: none;  
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click</button>
<button id="btn2">Click</button>
```