# Tailwindcss. Blue rectangle when click on mobile device

Tags: touch, tailwind-css

Help pls. When I press the Button on mobile devices, a blue rectangle appears on it. How can I remove this?

```
<a href="#1" class="block px-4 py-2 rounded-full bg-transparent border border-dashed hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-500 hover:border-transparent hover:shadow-md active:bg-gray-300">Link button</a>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```

It works well.

Comment: This isn't supported in Firefox or Safari: https://caniuse.com/?search=-webkit-tap-highlight-color

Comment: Please see more complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58165235/4378314